# dropdown menu and javascript form change

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to change some form options based on a dropdown selection. I think I wrote the javascript correctly but I am not sure. If someone could atleast get me pointed in the right direction or if there is a better way to accomplish the same thing that would be fine as well. I am a newbie to javascript.

Here is the code.

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="row requiredRow">
        <label for="ClassName" id="ClassName-ariaLabel">Class Name:</label>
        <input id="ClassName" name="ClassName" type="text" aria-labelledby="ClassName-ariaLabel" class="required" title="Class Name:. This is a required field">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="ProfessorName" id="ProfessorName-ariaLabel">Professor Name:</label>
        <input id="ProfessorName" name="ProfessorName" type="text" aria-labelledby="ProfessorName-ariaLabel">
    </div>
    <div class="row requiredRow">
        <label for="GradingScale" id="GradingScale-ariaLabel">Grading Scale:</label>
        <select id="GradingScale" name="GradingScale" aria-labelledby="GradingScale-ariaLabel" class="required" title="Grading Scale:. This is a required field">
            <option value="1">A,A-,B+,B,B-,C+,C,C-,D+,D,D-,F</option>
            <option value="2">A,B,C,D,F</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class='grades'>
        <script>
            var e = document.getElementById("GradingScale");
            var scale = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

            if (scale = 2) {
                document.write("<p>Grading Scale:</p><br />");
                document.write("A: <input type='text' name='grade-a'><br />");
                document.write("B: <input type='text' name='grade-b'><br />");
                document.write("C: <input type='text' name='grade-c'><br />");
                document.write("D: <input type='text' name='grade-d'><br />");
                document.write("F: <input type='text' name='grade-f'><br />");
            } else if (scale = 1) {
                document.write("<p>Grading Scale:</p><br />");
                document.write("A: <input type='text' name='grade-a'><br />");
                document.write("A-: <input type='text' name='grade-a-'><br />");
                document.write("B+: <input type='text' name='grade-b+'><br />");
                document.write("B: <input type='text' name='grade-b'><br />");
                document.write("B-: <input type='text' name='grade-b-'><br />");
                document.write("C+: <input type='text' name='grade-c+'><br />");
                document.write("C: <input type='text' name='grade-c'><br />");
                document.write("C-: <input type='text' name='grade-c-'><br />");
                document.write("D+: <input type='text' name='grade-d+'><br />");
                document.write("D: <input type='text' name='grade-d'><br />");
                document.write("D-: <input type='text' name='grade-d-'><br />");
                document.write("F: <input type='text' name='grade-f'><br />");
            }
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Class">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: this code can be optimize by 100 times

Comment: How could it be optimized?

Comment: 1. You don't seem to be having an onChange event for the `select` tag to modify the `grades` contents based on selection. 2. The script as it stands will execute only once and on load. 3. You don't have any default selected value for the drop-down.

Comment: @user2363217 use `for` loops and `arrays` instead of hardcoding whole form.

Comment: How would I add that to make it work? If you just showed an example that would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you should look into the suggestions provided by Ashwin.

You can modify your current code as below to work for now though. ([**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/Q8dqe/))

**JS Changes**

1. I have moved your entire script into the function `scaleChange`. This would make it easier for you to call the script whenever the option is changed.
2. Avoid using `document.write` lines, they are not a good practice as they repaint the page when called again.
3. `=` is an assignment operator and not a comparison operator. You should use `==` or `===` in the If/Else-If statements to compare the values.
4. I have added a `window.onload` line to populate your `grades` div based on the default selected value for your drop-down.
5. Put the modified code into your `<script>` tag and place it inside the `<head>` tag.

**HTML Changes**

1. I have added a `onChange` attribute to your select tag. This will make the `scaleChange` function be called whenever the selected option is changed.
2. I have made the first option as the default selected one by adding `selected` property to it.

**JS Code**

```
function scaleChange() {
    var e = document.getElementById("GradingScale");
    var scale = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var gradeDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("grades")[0];
    if (scale == 2) {
        gradeDiv.innerHTML = "<p>Grading Scale:</p><br />";
        gradeDiv.innerHTML += "A: <input type='text' name='grade-a'><br />";
        gradeDiv.innerHTML += "B: <input type='text' name='grade-b'><br />";
        gradeDiv.innerHTML += "C: <input type='text' name='grade-c'><br />";
        gradeDiv.innerHTML += "D: <input type='text' name='grade-d'><br />";
        gradeDiv.innerHTML += "F: <input type='text' name='grade-f'><br />";
    } else if (scale == 1) {
        gradeDiv.innerHTML = "<p>Grading Scale:</p><br />";
        gradeDiv.innerHTML += "A: <input type='text' name='grade-a'><br />";
        gradeDiv.innerHTML += "A-: <input type='text' name='grade-a-'><br />";
        gradeDiv.innerHTML += "B+: <input type='text' name='grade-b+'><br />";
        gradeDiv.innerHTML += "B: <input type='text' name='grade-b'><br />";
        gradeDiv.innerHTML += "B-: <input type='text' name='grade-b-'><br />";
        gradeDiv.innerHTML += "C+: <input type='text' name='grade-c+'><br />";
        gradeDiv.innerHTML += "C: <input type='text' name='grade-c'><br />";
        gradeDiv.innerHTML += "C-: <input type='text' name='grade-c-'><br />";
        gradeDiv.innerHTML += "D+: <input type='text' name='grade-d+'><br />";
        gradeDiv.innerHTML += "D: <input type='text' name='grade-d'><br />";
        gradeDiv.innerHTML += "D-: <input type='text' name='grade-d-'><br />";
        gradeDiv.innerHTML += "F: <input type='text' name='grade-f'><br />";
    }
}

window.onload = scaleChange;
```

**HTML Code** (only the `select` tag)

```
    <select id="GradingScale" name="GradingScale" aria-labelledby="GradingScale-ariaLabel" 
            class="required" title="Grading Scale:. This is a required field" 
            onChange='scaleChange();'>
        <option value="1" selected>A,A-,B+,B,B-,C+,C,C-,D+,D,D-,F</option>
        <option value="2">A,B,C,D,F</option>
    </select>
```